# Paypal IPN for cancel billing agreement

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an implementation for IPN requests from Paypal. 
It's working fine for everything but for *cancel billing agreement* notifications.

As per the documentation ( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) when:

**txn_type = mp_cancel**

I'm receiving a billing agreement cancelation, but I don't receive the billing agreement itself, and I need it to cancel it locally in my DB.

Is there any other way to obtain it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After some tests, I realized Paypal sends a parameter:

**mp_id**

with the billing agreement, but that's not in the documentation :(

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: What does the `mp_id` map to?